# Static routing on CentOS through managed switch

Tags: centos, redhat, routing, ip

I am a newbie in networking and I have a question regarding static routing through managed switch.

I have a cluster which are connected to a managed switch.
One of the node(call it head node) also has a connection to the external network for internet access.
My goal is to statically route all other nodes to the NIC on the head node to be able to connect to the internet.

Currently, the setup is something like this.

```
Managed switch ip = 192.168.50.1
```

eth1 on head node that has access to internet

```
ip = 10.36.134.54 
gateway = 10.36.134.1 
netmask = 255.255.255.0
```

eth2 on head node that is connected to managed switch

```
ip = 192.168.50.2
gateway = 192.168.50.1
netmask = 255.255.255.0
```

eth1 on node1 that is connected to managed switch

```
ip = 192.168.1.3
gateway = 192.168.50.1
netmask = 255.255.255.0
```

Currently, head node can talk to local nodes fine, and also get on the internet.
Other nodes however, only has access to local nodes, including head node.

For node1 to gain access to internet, I need to route to eth1 of head node. Am I correct?
To route to eth1 of head node from eth1 of node1, the path is

> node1 eth1 -> managed switch -> head node eth2 -> head node eth1

Is this correct?

Lastly, how do I do this? I read information about static routing on redhat and centOS, but I am having hard time understanding which machine I am supposed to implement this.

Thank you so much for your help! I greatly appreciate it.

EDIT:

Here is the current route -n info.

head node

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.50.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
10.36.134.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1006   0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         10.36.134.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

node1

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.50.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         192.168.50.2    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

I have changed the default gateway for node1 to the ip address of the head node, but internet still won't work. Can anyone help?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You're trying to solve the wrong problem. The problem is not routing these packets to the Internet, that's easy. The problem is getting the replies back.

Answer (score 1):

Each of your compute nodes will need a default route of 192.168.1.2 (head node eth2). You will then need to configure IP forwarding on the head node to allow the compute nodes access through it. You don't need to worry about the managed switch for this - it is "invisible" for the task you're trying to accomplish. You can also, if desired, enable masquerading on the head node, though doing so is optional.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After reading your answer, I created route-eth2 on the head node, and wrote
"10.36.134.0/24 via 10.36.134.54 dev eth1"
But this returns "RTNETLINK File Exists". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do not change any routing on the head node. On each of the compute nodes, add a default route through 192.168.1.2.

Comment: Thank you John. I did change the default route for all compute nodes to the ip address of the head node, but internet still doesn't work. I will post the route -n result above.